# Language file not loaded into extension directory

Tags: extensions, joomla-4.x

In my extension a language file which aren't loaded from the directory : /components/com_exten/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_exten.controllers.ini. In the Joomla! debug there are no parse error on this file

There are others language file in this directory which are loaded : en-GB.com_exten.models.ini, en-GB.com_exten.views.ini

I don't understand why only the file en-GB.com_exten.controllers.ini isn't loaded ?

Comment: The Joomla! debug console show no entry for /components/com_exten/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_exten.controllers.ini so how to debug now ?